# Transformation of virial coefficients from molar volume to pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws

I have the following virial equation for a real gas:

$Z = \frac{PV_m}{RT} = 1 + \frac{B}{V_m} + \frac{C}{V_m^2}$

I would like to transform the coefficients $B$ and $C$ so the equation is expressed in terms of pressure:

$Z = \frac{PV_m}{RT} = 1 + B'P+ C'P^2$

My book says that the transformations are:

$B' = \frac{B}{RT}$ and $C' = \frac{(C-B^2)}{(RT)^2}$

How are these derived? I can get the first one by:

$Z(\frac{1}{V_m}) = Z(P)$ and only considering $B$:

$1 + \frac{B}{V_m} = 1 + B'P$,

$\frac{BP}{RT} = B'P$,

$\frac{B}{RT} = B'$.

For the second one I also consider C:

$1 + \frac{B}{V_m} + \frac{C}{V_m^2}= 1 + B'P + C'P^2$,

$\frac{BP}{RT} + \frac{CP^2}{(RT)^2}= \frac{B}{RT}P + C'P^2$,

$\frac{CP^2}{(RT)^2}= C'P^2$,

$\frac{C}{(RT)^2}= C'$.

This result (mine) differs to the one given by the book. They have an additional $-B^2$ term in the numerator. Where is that term coming from?

Comment: Should not it be rather $\frac{pV_\mathrm{m}}{RT}$ ,or   $\frac{pV}{nRT}$  ? 

As either $pV = nRT$ either $pV_\mathrm{m} = RT$

Perhaps you follow a notation from a book, as I have seen this once, but it is wrong, IMHO.

Comment: @Poutnik yes, corrected. Doesn't matter - the problem still stands.

Comment: In the 3rd equation from a bottom you make substitution V_m=RT/P, but it is  true only if both B=0 and C=0

Try equation indexing by usage  \tag{N} at the end of equation Matjax expression. Like

\$\$X=Y+Z \tag{1}\$\$ --> 

$$X=Y+Z \tag{1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to take this:

$$Z = \frac{PV_m}{RT} = 1 + \frac{B}{V_m} + \frac{C}{V_m^2}+…\tag{1}$$

And transform it into this:

$$Z = \frac{PV_m}{RT} = 1 + B'P+ C'P^2+…\tag{2}$$

---

We begin by expressing (1) in terms of $\rho_m = 1/V_m$:

$$Z=1+B\rho_m+C\rho_m^2+…\tag{3}$$

We then multiply (2) and (3) by $RT\rho_m$ to get (4) and (5), respectively. Remember that $ZRT\rho=ZRT/V_m =P$, because $Z=PV_m/RT$.

$$RT\rho_m Z = P = RT\rho_m + RT\rho_mB'P+ RT\rho_mC'P^2+…\tag{4}$$
$$RT\rho_m Z= P = RT\rho_m + RTB\rho_m^2 + RTC\rho_m^3+…\tag{5}$$

Next, we use (5) to substitute for $P$ in (4):

$$P = RT\rho_m + RT\rho_mB'(RT\rho_m + RTB\rho_m^2 + RTC\rho_m^3+…) +$$
$$ RT\rho_mC'(RT\rho_m + RTB\rho_m^2 + RTC\rho_m^3+…)^2+…\tag{6}$$

Collecting all the $\rho_m^2$ terms from (5) and (6):

$$RTB=(RTB')(RT)$$
Rearranging leads to the desired $$B'=\frac{B}{RT} \tag{7}$$

Next, collecting all the $\rho_m^3$ terms from (5) and (6):

$$RTC=(RTB')(RTB)+(RTC')(RT)^2$$

Simplifying, rearranging, and making use of (7) leads to the desired
$$C' = \frac{C-B^2}{(RT)^2}\tag{8}$$

Comment: There is a derivation here too: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414386/virial-expansion-in-terms-of-pressure